Is there any intuitive reason why SQL syntax is handled in this order?
When SQL handles a query's order of operations it begins at the 'FROM' part. Therefore, a question that can be asked is: why are queries not entered as 'FROM mytable SELECT *;' but instead as 'SELECT * FROM mytable;'
I understand that only the creators of the language have a definite answer but was looking for some intuitive explanation that I may be missing.

Just that they wanted it to read like natural language as much as possible.

@NathanHughes They clearly didn't speak German then, or many other languages, where the verb often comes at the end of the sentence, after the accusative object.

It's timely that you have asked this, because last month a group of researchers at Google published a paper describing their idea of how to "fix" the syntax for SQL.
https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-research2023-media/pubtools/1004848.pdf
They note the same thing that you did, that the clauses of an SQL SELECT statement are not in the same order as they are typically executed by the RDBMS engine. They want to change SQL syntax to be more what they consider intuitive, i.e. it matches the way they think the query executes.

SQL is designed as a declarative language. You describe the result you want, and the engine is supposed to figure out the steps to get that result for you. It's meant to be an abstraction.
It's reasonable to me that you start a query with the select-list, describing the columns you want the result to include. Then after that, you specify tables and conditions.
E.g., "I want a list of US states and the sum of sales from each state. Get these data from the tables States and Sales. Include only sales that weren't returned."
SELECT us_state, COUNT(*)
FROM States JOIN Sales USING (us_state)
WHERE Sales.returned = false
GROUP BY us_state;

This is unfamiliar to some developers, who can't break their mindset that a programming language must describe the exact steps, in the exact order, to produce the result.
They want SQL to be an imperative language instead of declarative.
But SQL isn't a description of how the query should execute. It's a description of the result you want.

+1 to this answer. However, it's important to point out that Figure 2 is just one possible sequence of steps. For example, ORDER BY can come up before WHERE, and the SELECT list may definitively change the sequence of JOINs and FROM.

Auto-completion is a great advantage in modern realities. The current generation of spoiled developers do not want to manually type code. Pipe-syntax helps to implement it.

Also, do not forget that English is not the native language for all programmers. That's why your phrase starting with "I want a list of" sounds topsy-turvy in many other languages. PS: I agree that the developers must know English.

@AlexanderPetrov, Auto-completion could be implemented in a manner that after you type column names in the select-list, you can get suggestions for table names that contain those columns. Or else you could type your FROM clause first, then edit the select-list. One doesn't have to write the lines of SQL queries from top to bottom. In fact, I usually start with the FROM clause, and then move my cursor.

As for the English requirement, that is true of virtually every programming language (except perhaps LISP). Also, changing the order of clauses in SQL doesn't change the requirement that programmers recognize the keywords of the language. They don't have to be fluent in English to recognize a few key words.
